# How to use yum to reinstall all dependencies of a given package?

Tags: centos, yum

So I have a package that I am pretty sure that I removed part of one of its dependencies when removing something(as in rm). Long story. Basically what I want to do is have yum re-install the package and all of its dependencies so that it will re-install the files I removed. In the gentoo world you simply do it like this "emerge -e ". It seems yum should be able to do something similar.

I guess I could cobble together a script to list the deps and then parse those out and re-install all of them.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yeh, there's no easy way to do this ... however you can do a few things:

```
rpm -Va
```

...this will do a check on all the packages you have installed, and you can then reinstall anything that doesn't verify. Also:

```
yum reinstall $(repoquery --requires --recursive --resolve <pkg>)
```

...this will do what you asked for, although it's a big hammer.

Comment: quite useful on broken installs, like what I got lately after fedup.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Fedora and using `dnf` it's very easy. Just use the `dnf history rollback` feature.

http://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#history-command

Answer (score -2):

Also

```
yum reinstall $(yum list installed | awk '{print $1}')
```

or

```
rpm -qa | xargs yum reinstall
```

(depending on damage already done on the machine awk or xargs might not work)

Comment: That reinstalls **all** packages -- not just the dependencies of an individual package.