# How to force `yum reinstall` to overwrite changed files in a `/var` sub-directory?

Tags: linux, centos, yum, cmake

I have a software package[1] that is already being used by multiple users.
Its RPM is created with Cmake.

For historical reasons, the software package installs some files in a subdirectory of `/opt.`
Consequently, if any of these files is changed, Cmake assumes that since the changed file resides in `/opt`, it is a configuration file (AFAIK, as only config files should go under `/opt`), and if a `yum reinstall` of the package is performed, the changed file is *not* overwritten.

The obvious solution is to install to a non `/opt` location, e.g., to `/usr.`
This would work for new versions, but as I said, I have a user-base where `/opt` is used.

**Any ideas on how to force `yum reinstall` to *overwrite* the changed files in the `/opt` sub-directory?**

---

[1] OS: CentOS/RedHat 7.{3|4|6}

Comment: Have you simply tried `-force` and/or `/force`, with the number of point releases within the RedHat Enterprise Linux family, `RedHat 7` isn't descriptive enough to be helpful[.](https://superuser.com/questions/338296/how-to-use-yum-to-reinstall-all-dependencies-of-a-given-package)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, @Ramhound: where do you suggest I use -force? In `yum reinstall`?

Answer (score -1):

```
rpm -ivh --force packagename.rpm
```

to install the package replacing all existing files.

Comment: Not only is this wrong (this command will not cause `rpm` to overwrite existing files), it ignores the actual question asking for how to do this with `yum`.